# Change values smoothly over time in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, variables, var

I have a variable called "exposed" and I know already the sum of exposed people over time: have a look to understand

| i | exposed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | y |
| 2 | y |
| 3 | y |
| 4 | n |
| 5 | n |

So I have 3 exposed individuals and 2 are not.

```
t <- 5
#I know that each i in t :

sum(exposed[i]) <- c(3,4,1,4,5)
```

I created this line of code to capture the change in data:

```
evol <- list()

for(i in 1:t){evol[[i]]<- df}

for (i in 2:t) {
  # condition

}
```

My question is: what is the condition that I have to write to have in:

```
evol[[1]]
```

a data that looks like this:

| i | exposed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | y |
| 2 | y |
| 3 | y |
| 4 | n |
| 5 | n |

```
evol[[2]]
```

the data looks like this:

| i | exposed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | y |
| 2 | y |
| 3 | y |
| 4 | y |
| 5 | n |

```
evol[[3]]
```

a data that looks like this:

| i | exposed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | y |
| 2 | n |
| 3 | n |
| 4 | n |
| 5 | n |

I hope I made it clear;

Any ideas please;

kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want a list of dataframes based on the exposed sums.

Using lapply you can do

```
exposed <- c(3,4,1,4,5)

evol <- lapply(exposed, \(x) data.frame(i = seq_along(exposed), exposed = c(rep("y", x), rep("n", length(exposed) - x )))  )
```

```
evol[[1]]
  i exposed
1 1       y
2 2       y
3 3       y
4 4       n
5 5       n
```